# Can't Send S3 Bucket Notification to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to publish a bucket notification to an SQS queue when an object is created in S3. I have read that I might be trying to use boto3 in mixed ways (i.e. as client & resource but neither will work).

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

s3.create_bucket(Bucket='my-bucket',
    CreateBucketConfiguration={
        'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-2',
    },
)

bucket_notification = s3.BucketNotification('my-bucket')
s3_notification_config = {
    'QueueConfigurations': [
        {
            'QueueArn': 'arn:aws:sqs:location:number:number',
            'Events': [
                's3:ObjectCreated:*',
            ],
        },
    ],
}
response = bucket_notification.put(NotificationConfiguration=s3_notification_config)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'BucketNotification'
```

When I change the first line of code to be:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
```

I understand the first error but not sure how to work around it by using resource instead of client when presented with the second error.

Comment: I'd switch to the Resource API for creating the bucket. Not sure but wonder if region is your issue given the bucket constraint. Explicitly add your region_name when constructing the s3 resource object. Other than that, your notification code looks ok at first glance.

Comment: Have you added an access policy on the SQS side?